# Uniformly Integrable Martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, martingale

I have $(Y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ as a seq. of positive, independent r.v.'s whose expectation is 1 $\forall n$. I have the canonical filtration $\mathcal{F}_{n}=\sigma(Y_{k},k\leq n)$.

I have already shown that $\xi_{n}=\prod_{k=1}^{n}Y_{k}$ is an $\mathcal{F_{n}}$-martingale,  and that $(\sqrt{\xi_{n}})_{n\geq 0}$ is a $\mathcal{F_{n}}$-supermartingale. The question proceeds to add an additional condition, $\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{E}(\sqrt{Y_{k}})=0$.

My question: How do I use this additional condition to look at the convergence of $(\sqrt{\xi_{n}})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and use this to show whether or not $(\xi_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a uniformly integrable martingale?

My idea:

I would like to use a theorem stating that if $(X_{n},\mathcal{F_{n}})_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is an $L^{1}(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$-bounded martingale, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}=Y$ a.s., where Y is some random variable in the same space. However, I'm not totally sure how to leverage the information I know to show this. I then would like to show this martingale is right-closable, and thus uniformly integrable.

Any tips on showing this?

Comment: Bumping this to see if anyone has new thoughts

Comment: Please accept answers to your previous posts if they helped you.

Comment: And try focusing on *ONE* question in one post: while your title seems to imply there is only one quesion, the body asked many (some are ungrammatical) questions.

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks for those suggestions! I marked those previous ones correct, and changed some formatting around in this question to make it more clear.

Comment: Please double-check the conclusion.  $\{\xi_n\}$ may not necessarily be U.I.

Comment: Sorry you're right. The question is about discussing whether $\xi_{n}$ is U.I. or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With all the given conditions, $\{\xi_n\}$ is not uniformly integrable.

First, because $\{\xi_n\}$ is a martingale and $\sup_n E[\xi_n] = 1 < \infty$, by the theorem you cited (i.e., Theorem 35.5 in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley), $\xi_n$ converges to some r.v. $\eta$ with probability $1$. And because $\xi_n$ are positive, $\eta$ must be non-negative with probability $1$. This implies that $\{\sqrt{\xi_n}\}$ converges to $\sqrt{\eta}$ with probability $1$.

On the other hand, $\sup_n E[(\sqrt{\xi_n})^2] = \sup_n E[\xi_n] = 1 < \infty$ implies that $\{\sqrt{\xi}_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, which together with $\sqrt{\xi_n}$ converges to $\sqrt{\eta}$ with probability $1$ imply that (see the cited theorem $^\dagger$ after the answer):
\begin{align}
E[\sqrt{\eta}] = \lim_{n \to \infty} E[\sqrt{\xi}_n] = 
\prod_{k = 1}^\infty E[\sqrt{Y_k}] = 0.
\end{align}
This means $\sqrt{\eta}$, hence $\eta$, is $0$ with probability $1$.

But this then leads to the conclusion that $\{\xi_n\}$ is not uniformly integrable. Otherwise, we would conclude by the Theorem at the end of this answer again that $\lim_{n \to \infty} E[\xi_n] = E[\eta] = 0$, which contradicts with $E[\xi_n] = 1$ for all $n$.

---

$\dagger$ This is Theorem 25.12 in *Probability and Measure* by Patrick Billingsley.

> *If $X_n \overset{d}{\to} X$ and the $X_n$ are uniformly integrable, then $X$ is integrable and*
> \begin{align}
> E[X_n] \to E[X].
> \end{align}

Comment: Phenomenal. The pieces were there, I just could not see it. Thank you again.

Comment: It is a cute question (once you articulated it unambiguously :)) that embraces so many important notions in probability theory all together. +1